# Routing Error: No route matches [PUT] "/goals/4/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, put

I am trying to create a button to change a model record attribute from false to true. I'm using a form_tag as follows:

```
=form_tag edit_goal_path(goal), method: :post do
  =hidden_field_tag :purchased, value: true
  =submit_tag "Purchase"
```

It's haml, but feel free to post suggestions with ERB. I'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/goals/4/edit"
Rails.root: /home/ben/rails_projects/hartwig
```

However, I already have the following route from resources:

```
PUT     /goals/:id(.:format)    goals#update
```

My controller looks as following:

```
  def edit
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    if @goal.update_attributes(goal_params)
      redirect_to '/goals', notice: "Update successful!"
    else
      render '/'
    end
  end
  def goal_params
    params.require(:goal).permit(:item, :description, :picture, :purchased)
  end
```

How do I get this to work? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution to your problem could be adding a new method to the Goal Controller:

in goals_controller.rb

```
def purchase
@goal.update_attribute(:purchased, true)
end
```

and also add on top (just add :purchase)

```
before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :purchase]
```

in routes.rb change to

```
resources :goals do
 member do
  post 'purchase'
 end
end
```

to add a new post routes to your goals
now you will have a purchase_goal_path that you can use in your view like this:

```
link_to 'Purchase', purchase_goal_path(@goal), method: :post
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question says:

`I am trying to create a button to change a model record attribute from false to true`

so *why are you using a form for it?* I think a better approach would be to *create a link or button* that will call an **ajax method** or  a **normal method** with post route and update your attribute. You can achieve it by following these steps:

a. Create a **route for your custom action** where you'll update your attribute:

```
post 'purchase_update/:id' => "goal#update_purchase", as: update_purchase  #post as you want to send your goal id
```

b. create your custom method inside your controller:

```
def update_purchase
  @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  @goal.update_attribute(:purchased, true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to your_path, notice: 'purchase updated'}
    format.js {} #if you want to do something by ajax
  end
end
```

c. Create your link that will call this method:

```
=link_to "Purchase", update_purchase_path(@goal), method: post
```

and if you want to do it by ajax then

```
=link_to "Purchase", update_purchase_path(@goal), method: post, remote: true
```

Comment: I had to make the following changes to your post to make it work: `goals#update_purchase` `as: :update_purchase` and `method: :post`. 
However, I am getting an error from firefox saying "Corrupted Content Error: The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected." which I have no idea how to avoid.

Comment: @zenben1126 strange never encountered that error before and respond to block was there in case you wanted your action to respond to different type of requests